# Qspectre switch dll characteristica

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, spectre

as Microsoft started to update the compiler for Visual Studio (15.5 and 15.6 Prev3 and 4)i was wondering, if there is possibility to check, if a executable was compiled with the /qspectre or the equal /d2guardspecload switch, as it is possible with ASLR and DEP?

Best regards

Comment: I don't have the answer, but the BinSkim tool can warn if Qspectre could have been enabled but wasn't. Not sure about how it's implemented, but poked at the BinSkim source; it's somewhere around [here](https://github.com/microsoft/binskim/blob/1aebcf785647667e4e580e5267bc82d341749995/src/BinSkim.Rules/PERules/BA2024.EnableSpectreMitigations.cs#L263C49-L263C49)